# How to detect which type of chinese encoding has text file?

Tags: php, string, text, utf-8, iconv

on http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/ there are like 20 types of encoding for Chinese:

> Chinese EUC-CN, HZ, GBK, CP936, GB18030, EUC-TW, BIG5, CP950,
>   BIG5-HKSCS, BIG5-HKSCS:2004, BIG5-HKSCS:2001, BIG5-HKSCS:1999,
>   ISO-2022-CN, ISO-2022-CN-EXT

So I have a text file that is not UTF-8. It's ASCII. And I want to convert it to UTF-8 using `iconv()`. But for that I need to know the character encoding of the source.

How can I do that if I don't know chinese? :(

I noticed that:

```
$str = iconv('GB18030', 'UTF-8', $str);
file_put_contents('file.txt', $str);
```

produces an UTF-8 encoded file, while other encodings I tried (CP950, GBK and EUC-CN) produced an ASCII file. Could that mean that `iconv` is able to detect if the input encoding is wrong for the given string?

Comment: Take a look at [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)

Comment: The most reliable way would probably be having the user decide

Comment: @david yea i know about that. but I can only use it to find out if the source is UTF-8 or not. I know it's not lol..

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

Comment: Maybe it's worth looking at the root of the problem. Why do you not know the encoding of these files?

Comment: well they are subtitles from opensubtitles.org. And most of them are in ASCII...

Comment: @thelolcat, you are right - tried alle possible combinations using text from http://generator.lorem-ipsum.info/_chinese - cannot produce any other result than UTF8 or ASCII by mb_detect_erncoding :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This **may** work for your needs (but I really cant tell). Setting the locale and utf8_decode, and using `mb_check_encoding` instead of mt_detect_encoding seems to give some useful output..

```
// some text from http://chinesenotes.com/chinese_text_l10n.php
// have tried both as string and content loaded from a file
$chinese = '譧躆 礛簼繰 剆坲姏 潧 騔鯬 跠 瘱瘵瘲 忁曨曣 蛃袚觙';
$chinese=utf8_decode($chinese);

$chinese_encodings ='EUC-CN,HZ,GBK,CP936,GB18030,EUC-TW,BIG5,CP950,BIG5-HKSCS,BIG5-HKSCS:2004,BIG5-HKSCS:2001,BIG5-HKSCS:1999,ISO-2022-CN,ISO-2022-CN-EXT';

$encodings = explode(',',$chinese_encodings);

//set chinese locale
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'Chinese');

foreach($encodings as $encoding) {
    if (@mb_check_encoding($chinese, $encoding)) {
        echo 'The string seems to be compatible with '.$encoding.'<br>';
    } else {
        echo 'Not compatible with '.$encoding.'<br>';
    }
}
```

outputs

```
The string seems to be compatible with EUC-CN
The string seems to be compatible with HZ
The string seems to be compatible with GBK
The string seems to be compatible with CP936
Not compatible with GB18030
The string seems to be compatible with EUC-TW
The string seems to be compatible with BIG5
The string seems to be compatible with CP950
Not compatible with BIG5-HKSCS
Not compatible with BIG5-HKSCS:2004
Not compatible with BIG5-HKSCS:2001
Not compatible with BIG5-HKSCS:1999
Not compatible with ISO-2022-CN
Not compatible with ISO-2022-CN-EXT
```

It is total guess. Now it at least seems to recognise some of the chinese encodings. Delete if it is total junk.

Answer (score 2):

I have zero experience with chinese encoding and I know this question is tagged `iconv`, but if it will get the job done, then you may try [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/mb_detect_encoding) to detect your encoding; The second argument is list of encodings to check, and there is a user-crafted comment about chinese encodings:

> For Chinese developers: please note that the second argument of this
>   function DOES NOT include 'GB2312' and 'GBK' and the return value is
>   'EUC-CN' when it is detected as a GB2312 string.

so maybe it will work if you explicitly provide full list of chinese encodings as a second argument? It could work like this:

```
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($chineseString, 'GB2312,GBK,(...)');
if($encoding) $utf8text = iconv($encoding, 'UTF-8', $str);
```

you may also want to play with third argument (`strict`)

Comment: tried that, with strict too, and from that list it returns EUC-CN, CP936, GB18030... I don't think a file can have multiple encodings

Comment: @thelolcat can you copy and paste the return from using mb_detect_encoding? i'm not aware of a comma separated string of encoding types that are returned from that function

Comment: it returns one only, but I tried changing the order of the input encodings, and it returns others too

Answer (score 2):

What makes it hard to detect the encoding is the fact that octet sequences decode to valid characters in several encodings, but the result makes sense in only the correct encoding. What I've done in these cases is take the decoded text and go to an [automatic translation service](http://translate.google.com/) and see if you get back legible text or a jumble of syllables.

You can do this programmatically for example by analyzing trigraph frequencies in the input text. Libraries like [this one](https://code.google.com/p/uchardet/) have already been created to solve this problem, and there are external programs that do it, but I have yet to see anything with a PHP API. This approach is not fool-proof though.